# Confused with a high school conditional probability problem

Tags: probability, independence

In a past paper question for maths, I have encountered the following problem which is confusing me. The question states that:

When drivers approach crossroads, a survey shows that:

40% went straight on;

35% turned left;

25% turned right.

Assume that the drivers choose direction independently.

Find the probability that the next three vehicles approaching the crossroads will **all turn left given that none turns right.**

The answer provided is:
$$P(\text{all left}\mid \text{none turn right}) = {0.35^3 \over(1-0.25)^3}=\ 0.102\ \text{(3 s.f)}$$

This is where I'm confused. For independent events should it not be the following: 
$$P(\text{all left}\mid \text{none turn right}) = P(\text{all  left}) = 0.35^3 = 0.0429 \text{ (3 s.f)?}$$

Edit:

I have realized I misunderstood the independence part of the question, but I'm still left confused over the answer. From the equation $P(A\mid B) = {P(A\cap B) \over P(B)}$, how does $P(A\cap B)$ equal $P(\text{all left})$?

Comment: The trick is: 'Joey turns left' is independant from 'Cindy turns right', but 'Joey turns left' is not independant form 'Joey does not turns right'...

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the statement "drivers choose directions independently."

Comment: Btw, the exponents is the proof given and in your attempt are 3's, not 2's, aren't they ?

Comment: Yeah, I updated it to be 3's. And from your first comment, I gained more understanding about the question (and have updated the question accordingly), though I still don't understand how 0.35^3 = P(A∩B)?

Comment: See my edit to the question for the proper use of \text{} in MathJax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might make the problem clearer to you if it was worded

> Assume that the drivers choose direction independently **of each other**.

Notice that if person X does not make a right, then he either goes straight or makes a left. Then if person X makes a left and does not make a right, then person X makes a left. If all three make a left and all three don't make a right, then all three make a left. This is how $A\cap B = A$, where $A$ is "all left" and $B$ is "none make a right".

Answer (score 0):

I do not learn the method you are using, but this is my explanation.

All turning left is not the same as all turning left and non turns right. For the later, you already knew none of them will turn right, so the drivers can only turn left or go straight. This should give a higher chance of turning left as now the drivers are only left with two choices instead of three. (If none turns right, they can only go straight or turn left.)

The calculations:
(35/(35+40))^3

Since none can turn right, drivers are left to turn left or go straight. These two will sum up to 100% as drivers cannot turn right(the denominator). Simply find the chance of one turning left and power it by three.